# What is the best practice regarding uniqueItems: true Arrays in Openapi

Tags: arrays, json, angular, openapi, openapi-generator

I am generating Angular 12 code with OpenAPI Generator from JSON made from Java app. When generating API model from the JSON, the app creates model:

```
export interface UserDto { 
roles?: Set<RoleDto>;
}
```

From JSON file that states:

```
"UserDto":
{"type":"object","properties":
{"roles":{"uniqueItems":true,"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/components/schemas/RoleDto"}}}}
```

Which in turn is generated from Java model:

```
public class User {
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

This is the default and correct behavior of the generator starting version 5.0 but I am getting error 400 - Bad Request when sending a call using this code.

Switching to an older version of the generator or changing Set to Array by hand solves the issue.

What am I missing? What should I do differently for it to work with the newest version which translates the Java code more accurately?

JSON file automatically generated from Java app made with Spring Boot. I am using OpenAPI specification in JSON in version 3.0.1 and generating code to Angular 12.2.4 with openapi-generator-cli 2.4.1 and OpenAPI tools 5.1.0 (with Set generated, doesn't work) or 4.3.1 (with Array generated - works).

Answer (score 1):

The current solution is to configure a type mapping as option when generating

```
--type-mappings=set=Array
```

Like this in example:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-6.0.1.jar generate --type-mappings=set=Array -i api-definition.json -g typescript-angular -o generated/client
```

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/8258